# Newer style PHP ternary operator has undesired result with isset function

Tags: php

I am having issue with PHP's ternary operator, since PHP version 5.3 you are able to replace the shorthand ternary operator with an even shorter version

```
// Older version
$route = isset($test) ? $test : 'test is NOT set';


// Newer version as of 5.3
$route = isset($test) ?: 'test is NOT set';
```

Now on the newer version, if `$test` is not set. it works fine.  However when it is set because of the `isset()` method, it is returning `true` or `1` instead of the value.

Do I have to use the older longer method to get `$route` to equal the value of `$test` instead of a boolean value of `1` ?

Comment: You could use `$route = $test ?: 'test is NOT set';` instead.

Comment: If you don't mind suppressing error messages you can still use the shorthand.  It's not the 'correct' or 'pretty' way to do it, but still works - $route = @$test ?: 'test is NOT set';

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the longer version.

Quoting the [docs](http://ar.php.net/ternary):

> Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

So the correct behaviour for your shorthand version is to return the result of evaluating `isset($test)`. Not of `$test` as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from **PHP 7**, you can use the **null coalescing operator**:

```
$route = $test ?? 'test is NOT set';
```

which is equivalent to

```
$route = isset($test) ? $test : 'test is NOT set';
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/ro/migration70.new-features.php) you can find some details:

> The null coalescing operator (`??`) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with `isset()`. It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.